# Url translate as request to another folder

Tags: .htaccess

I need solution for this:

I have domain: **www.test.com**

with DOCUMENT_ROOT: **/var/www/test.com/**

I have web app placed in **/var/www/test.com/apps/my-app/www**

and I need accesible from **www.test.com/apps/my-app/** without redirects and without **www**

htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apps/my-app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apps/my-app/www/ [PT]
```

Pages **www.test.com/apps/my-app/WHATEVER** is ok, but when i put URL **www.test.com/apps/my-app/** page will be redirects to **www.test.com/apps/my-app/www**

Thank you

Comment: Ok, so what have you one to achieve it? (Apart from asking on [so])

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/var/www/test.com/apps/my-app/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apps/my-app/

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!www/).*)$ www/$1 [L,NC]
```